# yii perfomance optimization for gridview searching

Tags: php, performance, yii, query-optimization, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on yii advanced template, where there is an User list using gridview. I am trying to optimize the search with in the listing. I have gone through the documentation https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-performance-tuning , but for searching I couldnt find any improvemnt.
NB: We do have 11 million records.

Comment: This is almost **certainly** a database optimization issue and nothing to do with the framework code. 11 million records should present NO problems in terms of speed if your database is indexed properly. Check your indexes, especially on join columns that are involved in Gridview searches. I can pretty much guarantee that will solve your problem, I have seen it hundreds of times.

Comment: add  your table schema  ..  with the indexes related to the tables , the sql code or acqtivequery code  and tell us the most use query search column/field you use

Comment: I am using 2 columns for searching. id and username. Both are indexed. For listing , I am fechting first 20 only, and I got result with in 3 sec. But if i try search it is taking 40 sec.

Comment: I am ising Activerecord and gridview for listing

Comment: Show some code. How many queries do you have in your debug toolbar? How long your query load if you run it in your database/phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of active record try to write plain query and populate gridview.
2. Avoid unnecessary linking like relations